# XmlReader to return node as-is without children

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader

I'm traversing a large XML document using `XmlReader` and stitching it into a much smaller and more manageable `XmlDocmuent`.  Along the way, I find a node that's interesting so to move it I do this:

```
        targetDoc.LoadXml("<result></result>");
        // Some interesting code removed
        using (XmlReader r = XmlReader.Create(file))
        {
            while (r.Read())
            {
                if (r.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                {
                    if (r.Name == match)
                    {
                        // Put the node into the target document
                        targetDoc.FirstChild.InnerXml = r.ReadOuterXml();
                        return targetDoc;
                    }
                }
             }
         }
```

This is all well and good, except I'd like to include the node *without its descendents*.  What I'm interested in is the node itself with its attributes.  The descendents are very large, bulky and uninteresting at this point.  (And reading them into memory all at once will cause out of memory errors...)

Is there an easy way to get the text (?) of the found element with its attributes -- but not its descendents -- into the target document?

Comment: You should not use `new XmlTextReader()`. Use `XmlReader.Create()` instead.

Comment: It was actually passed as an argument from the outer function (not shown) and typed for SO.  Edited so hopefully I'll get a helpful answer instead.

Comment: Trying to help others who don't know better than to copy/paste the code they see here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a Built-in way of doing it. I think you have to read out the Attributes and content yourself.

e.g.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var xml = @"<root>
                                <parent a1 = 'foo' a2 = 'bar'>Some Parent text
                                    <child a3 = 'frob' a2= 'brob'> Some Child Text
                                    </child>
                                </parent>
            </root>";
            var file = new StringReader(xml) ;

            using (XmlReader r = XmlReader.Create(file))
            {
                while (r.Read())
                {
                    if (r.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                    {
                        if (r.Name == "parent")
                        {
                            var output = new StringBuilder();
                            var settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
                            settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
                            using (var elementWriter = XmlWriter.Create(output, settings))
                            {   

                                elementWriter.WriteStartElement(r.Name);

                                elementWriter.WriteAttributes(r,false);
                                elementWriter.WriteValue(r.ReadString());
                                elementWriter.WriteEndElement();
                            }

                            Console.WriteLine(output.ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }


            if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
                Console.ReadLine();

        }
```

Will produce

```
<parent a1="foo" a2="bar">Some Parent text</parent>
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try XmlNode.CloneNode(bool deep) method.

deep: true to recursively clone the subtree under the specified node; false to clone only the node itself.

Comment: He doesn't have an XmlNode to clone because the descendents are too bulky.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily a great way, but you can read the string until you get to the end of the start tag, and then manually append an end tag and load that into an XmlDocument.

edit:

Thinking something like:

```
string xml = r.ReadOuterXml();
int firstEndTag = xml.IndexOf('>');
int lastStartTag = xml.LastIndexOf('<');
string newXml = xml.Substring(0, firstEndTag) + xml.Substring(lastStartTag);
```

This might not be valid at all, given that there's a large string right there.  Your way might be the best.  Neither are pretty, but I personally can't think of a better way, given your constraints (which is not to say that a better way doesn't exist).

Comment: I thought of something like: `if (r.HasAttributes)
                                for (int i = 0; i < r.AttributeCount; i++)
                                {
                                    r.MoveToAttribute(i);
                                    atts[r.Name] = r.Value;  // Dictionary<string, string>
                                    
                                }`  And then rebuild the XML for the node as you suggest, but that seemed... ugly.